# PHP form sending email but not sending attachement

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I am receiving  email with body but I cannot get attachment. I admit that this question has been asked before but I am bit new to this I am facing problem. I tried many other questions but I am not getting this. Here is my code

```
<?php
//$to_mail = "architects@palavin.com,t.lavin@palavin.com,12yorkcourt@gmail.com";
$to_mail = "myemail@gmail.com";
//$cc="paul@enhance.ie";
$mail_sent = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 //echo "the form was submitted";

$name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
if($name == "")
 $error = true;

$email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
if($email == "")
 $error = true;


$phone = trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone']));
$address = trim(strip_tags($_POST['address']));
$description = trim(strip_tags($_POST['description']));
$select = trim(strip_tags($_POST['select']));
$address = trim(strip_tags($_POST['address']));
$location = trim(strip_tags($_POST['location']));
$availability = trim(strip_tags($_POST['availability']));
$brand = trim(strip_tags($_POST['brand']));

 $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
 $file_name = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
 $file_size = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
 $file_error = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];

 if($file_error>0)
 {
 die('upload error');
 }
 //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
 $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
 $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
 fclose($handle);

 $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode(($content)));

if($error != true){




 $headers = 'From: "Contact Form" <no-reply@pintribe.com>'."\r\n";
 //$headers .= 'CC: "'.$cc.'" <'.$cc.'>'."\r\n";
 $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "";

 $subject = "PinTribe Form";
 $boundary = md5(time());

 //attachment
 $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
 $body .="Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";

 $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
 $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n\r\n";

 $body .= $encoded_content ."\r\n";
 $message = "New Contact message, received from: <br /> \n ";
 $message .= "<b>Item Name</b> ".$name."<br /> \n";
 $message .= "<b>Email</b> ".$email."<br /> \n";
 $message .= "<b>Email</b> ".$brand."<br /> \n";

 $message .= "<b>Contact Person</b> ".$phone."<br /> \n";
 $message .= "<b>Address</b> ".$address."<br /> \n";
 $message .= "<b>Category</b> ".$select."<br /> \n";
 $message .= "<b>Description</b> ".$description."<br /> \n";
 $message .= "<b>Location</b> ".$location."<br /> \n";
if(@mail($to_mail,$subject,$message,$headers))
 {
 echo "mail has been sent";
 $mail_sent = 1;
 }
 else echo "mail not sent";
} else {
 echo 'validation error';
}
}
?>
```

HTML

```
 <form role="form" action="send_form_email.php" method="post" class="login-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <div class="form-group">
     <span>Attach Photos</span>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-file fa fa-plus">
                                             <input type="file" name="my_file">
                                            </label>
                                            <br>
                                <small>A maximum of 3 photos. Make sure Photos are bigger than 450 px X 850px</small>
                                            </div>
                                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">submit Form</button>
                                </form>
```

I can see everything means Body is been received but unable to receive Attached file

Comment: Any reason why the body variable is not used in the mail command nor as part of the message?

Comment: don't build your own mime emails. use phpmailer or swiftmailer. both will reduce all of that pointless mime-building to a single `AddAttachment(...)`-type call.

Comment: I second @MarcB there is no point implementing this on your own when there are awesome libraries around. I highly recommend http://swiftmailer.org/